# Autocompletion not working in Jupyter notebook on Vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, autocomplete

I am using Jupyter on VsCode. I have two questions about its autocomplete feature. I have  Jupyter Keymap, Jupyter Notebook Renderers, IntelliCode, and Pylance installed.

I have  titanic_train.csv in the folder I m working on and my first few lines of codes are as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import  numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline 
train=pd.read_csv('./titanic_train.csv')
train.head()
```

which gives this

[image]

but when I type first initial of Survived column name as train['Sur'] I expect it to give me some suggestion about its autocomplete feature but nothing comes up and I have to type the full name each letter correctly, every time, which is tiring and easy to mistype of course. How to make its autocomplete feature work?

My second question is about tab key. When I use it, it doesn't work as one expects, meaning autocompletion again. it creates 4 to 5 spaces instead. How can I use tab instead of ctrl+space on Vscode and Jupyter?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, there is no way to gain the name.

For the second question, **TAB** means 4 **space** usually. You can change it in the lower right corner of the vscode interface.

[image]

[image]

You can also change the size of **TAB**.

[image]